# Update dropDownList using SQL query

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am trying to update my dropdownlistB according to the categoryId chosen in dropdownlistA Using this code:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListA" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceA" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Description" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListB" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceB" DataTextField="Title" DataValueField="Title"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceA" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MainDbConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Description] FROM [BookCategory]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceB" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MainDbConnectionString1 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Title] FROM [BooksInfo] WHERE ([CategoryId] = @CId)">
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="" Name="CId" QueryStringField="SELECT [CategoryId] FROM [BookCategory]" Type="Int32" />
     </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I am new to using SQL and queries in ASP.NET and cant figure out what Im doing wrong, dropdownlistB stays empty. (AutoPostBack = true in dropdownlistA, so it should update?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the `asp:ControlParameter`  like this

```
<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DropDownListA" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                                  Name="EmpID" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
```

So the the query is based on the selection of **DropDownListA**.

Comment: Do I need to add something to my web.config to be able to use this? says Im missing something

Comment: Without the error message it is hard to say, I will defer to the documenation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.controlparameter(v=vs.100).aspx